# Firebase NodeJS retrieving data issues

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Firebase and am currently doing a mini project on that. As of now, I have initialised Firebase Cloud Functions with Nodejs and am currently trying to query some data from Firebase database here.

```
exports.timetableUpdate = functions.firestore.document('/users/{documentId}')
    .onUpdate(async (snap, context) => {
        const userUid = context.params.documentId;
        const token = [];
        admin.firestore()
            .collection('userNotificationTokens')
            .doc(String(userUid))
            .onSnapshot(doc => {
                const data = doc.data()
                token.push(data.token);
            })
        //const tokens = ['cMCd_tWQxas:APA91bEwgeqzG2sFp5DtoUprdXVLlgcUAAG569lrVdrK4M3zZ8JMGME-0gifQRYV6Fm4_eOsmru6QRajlgAlmEEghs0HHLcj7j9vGwr8ZRlBQ6h_Al_2XRdP4QDMauI9OkrOzSoanNwY']
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                tile: 'Timetable Update',
                body: 'You have updated your timetable!'
            }
        }
        const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
        // eslint-disable-next-line promise/always-return
        .then((res) =>
        { 
            console.log("Message sent successfully!" ,res.body) 
           // return "Message sent successfully! Is this an error?" + res;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Message failed!", error)
        }); 
    });
```

I want to be able to query value of `token` attribute in my database & then send a notification with it. The mapping in my database looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC4VF.png) currently.

My path to each mapping `userNotificationTokens` is retrieved with `userUid`. However, I am unable to do so, as the error log in Cloud functions states that my array(`token`) is empty. Any kind souls who can help me out with retrieving the token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calls to Firestore, FCM, and most modern cloud APIs happen asynchronously. The results of those calls are only available inside their `then()` callback.

You can most easily see what this means by placing a few log statements:

```
exports.timetableUpdate = functions.firestore.document('/users/{documentId}')
.onUpdate(async (snap, context) => {
    console.log("Before starting read");
    admin.firestore()
        .collection('userNotificationTokens')
        .doc(String(userUid))
        .onSnapshot(doc => {
            console.log("Got data");
        })
    console.log("After starting read");
});
```

When you run this code, it'll log:

> Before starting read
>
> After starting read
>
> Got data

This is probably not the order you expected, but it is working as designed. And it explains why your code doesn't work: by the time you call `admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)`, the `token.push(data.token)` hasn't run yet so `token` is still empty.

---

The solution is to handle the asynchronous nature of calls correctly. Normally I do that by putting any code that needs the data from the database inside the callback. But since you're always using `async` and `await`, that might be easier for you:

```
exports.timetableUpdate = functions.firestore.document('/users/{documentId}')
.onUpdate(async (snap, context) => {
    const userUid = context.params.documentId;
    const token = [];
    const doc = await admin.firestore()
        .collection('userNotificationTokens')
        .doc(String(userUid))
        .get();
        
    const data = doc.data()
    token.push(data.token);

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            tile: 'Timetable Update',
            body: 'You have updated your timetable!'
        }
    }
    const res = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
    return null;
});
```

Comment: Wow thank you! Works like a charm & thanks a lot for enlightening me on the meaning of `await`!